# How to achieve a controlled swirl pattern that conforms to a sphere?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

[image: swirly eye]

In Adobe Illustrator, how can one recreate the eyeball in this image? The best method I have is to create a stack of parallel lines (alternating black and white, evenly sized, evenly spaced) and warp them over and over (any combination of warp-twist, warp-wave, warp-fisheye) until I get something close to this. But it doesn't seem very efficient and the result is not as precise as this image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Illustrator's **Twirl Tool**. It's under the Width tool (at least in the version I'm using.)

[image]

---

Note: *Explaining* this (or reading the explanation) takes **considerably** more time than actually *doing* it does. From rectangles to mapped symbol really only takes a couple minutes.

---

Create a series of rectangles.

[image]

- You want the rectangles to have *a lot of anchor points*. So... repeatedly choose `Object > Path > Add Anchor Points` until you've got *way more* anchors than you think you need. The more anchors you have the smoother the "swirls" will be.

[image]

- You need *all* these anchor points to be **smooth points**.
- To convert them all to smooth anchors... select them all, then **deselect just one of the anchors** by holding down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and clicking an anchor using the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow).
- You can then click the `Covert to Smooth Point` button ([image]) in the **Control Bar** to convert all the anchors to smooth.
- Afterwards, go back and select that *one anchor* you deselected and convert that to smooth as well.

<sub>(It's not possible to select all then convert the anchors. At least 1 anchor on a path has to *not* be selected for the convert buttons to appear.)</sub>

Typically you see the ends of the rectangles bulge a bit once the anchors are converted.... This doesn't matter and is expected.

[image]

---

Grab the **Twirl Tool** in the toolbar..

[image]

... then **double-click the Twirl Tool** after it's selected. I've tried double-clicking in the popup tools but that never works. One has to choose the tool first, then it can be double-clicked it in the toolbar.  Or detach the popup so it becomes a floating tool group... then you can double-click the Twirl Tool.

Adjust the tool options.... I'm using a *legacy version of Illustrator*. So, your Options dialog will probably *look* different. But the options available should be similar.

[image]

I prefer to *deselect* the `Simplify` option (for pretty much *any* warp tool, *every* time) ... and often also the `Detail` option.. but sometimes `Detail` can be helpful. It is here. And I'm using a tablet so I've got the `Intensity` set to `Pen Pressure` but 40-50% is a decent setting. You can always undo and change this and try again if you find it's too intense.

Now... simply hover over the rectangles and click..

<sub>(I've "hidden edges" in the animation below so it's clearer, but all the rectangles *are* selected.)</sub>

- To change the size of the Warp Brush hold down <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> and click-drag. Also holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> will constrain the brush to a circle. You want the warp brush to be a circle that falls within the area of rectangles. You do *not* want the brush larger than the rectangles.
- The longer you hold down the click the more twirling will occur.
- You can use `Edit > Undo` and keep experimenting.

[image]

You can reduce the `Twirl Rate` in the Twirl Tool Options to slow down the twirl if necessary.

---

[image]

<sub>(Open this image in a new window/tab to see it better.)</sub>

---

Then, once you have a twirl you like... You can create a **Symbol** of the artwork by dragging it to the **Symbols Panel**...

[image]

And then map the art to a 3D sphere (using legacy 3D effect in Illustrator here)...

[image]

So you get a swirl for the eyeball...

[image]

Then, if necessary..

- `Object > Expand Appearance`
- Delete all no-fill no-stroke objects (there's typically a few, using `Select > Same >` helps.)
- Then hit the `Merge` button on the **Pathfinder Panel**.

[image]

Comment: You dont need to add detail upfront. You can just take the detail slider up it does more or less same thing dynamically. This is the answer i didnt want to write :)

Comment: Ooop.. You're correct @joojaa Rather than adding anchor points, one can simply increase the `Detail` option for the the Twirl Tool. (I almost always disable that option for warps.. seems it's actually handy for "twirling".) I do find though, adding the anchors up front helps a bit around the edges of the twirl though.

Comment: @Scott I would love to email you about a project if you don't mind.

Comment: @trndjc be aware, I'm an inherently skeptical person. `:)` but.. check my profile.

Answer (score 1):

Non-human iris, no pupil

You can use the classic 3D effect "Revolve" to force your pattern to spherical:

[image]

In the left there's your array of lines, actually rectangles because the strokes are outlined. It has got a little bloat and twirl effects to break the regularity. It's not the same as the one used in your role model, but that's not the point. I show a way to spherize it with the classic 3D effect Revolve.

The distorted pattern must be dragged to the symbols panel to be able to use it in 3D effects.

In the middle there's a strokeless white half circle. Effect Revolve makes it sphere. It has still shading, but that must be changed to "no shading".

In the right option Map Art is applied to the sphere. The Artwork is the distorted line array. The 2 different versions are got by rotating the view angle.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. While this does work, I think it would be better to have shown a twirl pattern like the OP's mapped to a sphere. Something [like this perhaps](https://imgur.com/WnooAhI). Feel free to use this image in your answer if you want.